# Object Transformer/Adapter

Tags: c#, design-patterns

In C#/.NET, what is the best approach to map data-fields(some arbitrary object) you are 'GET'ing from one RESTful end-point/system, and then 'POST'ing it to another RESTful end-point/system(which is already-known). Here is some sample code...
Edit-In this code I am mocking a Source object. But in reality, I am trying to write this in such a way, that it would be dynamic. The only conclusion I can devise, is to place the resposibility on the user to provide a field-mappings file(json or xml) that would map the data fields of the source object(since they presumably know their own system the best) to the well-known destination system. 
The field-mappings would essentially be a key-value pair, with the destination field serving as the 'key' and the source-field would be the 'value'. Edit-I added 'Adapter' to the Title.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using NSubstitute;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsAppJsonNet
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
       {
        //GET SOURCE OBJECT
        dynamic sourceObjdyn = GetSourceObj();

        //GET FIELD MAPPINGS
        Dictionary<string, string> fieldMappings = GetFieldMappings();

        //NEW UP DESTINATION OBJECT
        DestinationObject destinationObject = new DestinationObject();

        foreach (var fieldMapping in fieldMappings)
        {
            foreach (var prop in destinationObject.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                if (prop.Name == fieldMapping.Key)
                {
                    prop.SetValue(destinationObject,    sourceObjdyn.GetType().GetProperty(fieldMapping.Value).GetValue(sourceObjdyn));                        
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(destinationObject);
        //Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static Dictionary<string,string> GetFieldMappings()
    {
        string jsonFieldMappings = @"       
            {
                ""SSN"":""ssn"",      
                ""GEN_ID"":""sysid"",      
                ""BIRTH_DATE"":""dob""      
            }";

        //DESERALIZE FIELD-MAPPINGS
        Dictionary<string, string> fieldMappings =    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonFieldMappings);

        return fieldMappings;
    }

    private static dynamic GetSourceObj()
    {
        //MOCK A SOURCE OBJECT
        var sourceObj = Substitute.For<ISourceObject>();
        sourceObj.dob.Returns("10/10/20112");
        sourceObj.ssn.Returns("555-66-5555");
        sourceObj.sysid.Returns("9876");

        return sourceObj;
    }

}//end program

public class DestinationObject
{
    //ctor
    public DestinationObject()
    { }

    public string SSN { get; set; }
    public string GEN_ID { get; set; }
    public string BIRTH_DATE { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("BIRTH_DATE = {0},\nSSN = {1},\nGEN_ID = {2}",  this.BIRTH_DATE, this.SSN, this.GEN_ID);
    }

}//end class

public interface ISourceObject
{
     string ssn { get; set; }
     string sysid { get; set; }
     string dob { get; set; }
}

}//end namespace
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are using some auto-mapping library, the best way is to simply write a function:

```
public SecondApiObject ConvertFirstApiObject(FirstApiObject data)
{
     // return a new object with the fields from the first one
}
```

If you have an `IEnumerable` of these, you can use `Select` to invoke the transform operation:

```
listOfFirstApiObjects.Select(ConvertFirstApiObject);
```

And if its *always* an IEnumerable, you can also just inline the conversion as a lambda in the `Select` arguments.

Comment: What if FirstApiObject is unknown?

Comment: @DemetriusBerlioz Then it is impossible. If you don't know the fields, you can't do a mapping. You can reflect to *detect* certain fields, but doing so is going to be tenuous at best

Comment: You may or may have not noticed that I tagged this question with "designpattern". Doesn't the GOF Adapter pattern apply to this?

Comment: @DemetriusBerlioz I'm not familiar enough with that particular pattern to be sure. Sorry :(

Comment: just reviewed Paul Kimmel's book LINQ Unleased for C#(chap 10) and you are correct Bradley.